# How to compute all undirectioned connected graphs that can be constructed from given V nodes and E edges

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I have 8 "types" of nodes, that can each appear once, twice or 3 times in one graph. Types 1,3 and 5 can appear 1 time, types 2 and 4 can appear two times and types 6, 7 and 8 can appear three times each. In total  V=16 possible nodes.

Each node can have one, two or three connections points, depending on its type. In total 32 connection points possible.

How can I compute how many graphs I can build from these nodes and their connection points?

Also, one node cannot be connected to itself.

[image]

Comment: When counting the graphs, do the "types" of the vertices make them distinguishable? Which type has what number of connection points? Are the numbers you gave for the number of connections the maximum allowed or must there be exactly that many connections ... ? I don't think this is very clear.

Comment: Yes, the types of vertices makes them distinguishable, i.e., in total you can consider 16 "independent" vertices. Vertices of type 1, 5 and 7 have 1 connection point. When a node of type 1 exists then also its connection point exists. Nodes of type 2, 3 and 6 have 2 connection points, and nodes of type 4 and 8 have three connections points. When an node appears in one graph all its connection points must be present also.

Comment: You mentioned 16 *possible* nodes. Could there be fewer? Do graphs with, say, 8 nodes, one of each type, count as well?

Comment: Yes, there could be from graphs with only 1 node to graphs to max. 16.

Comment: Maybe not relevant for me, but let's consider null graphs are not allowed.

Comment: Okay, thanks. How about the connection points? 0 to 32 connections?

Comment: That strongly depends on which nodes one graph has. Consider: node 1, 2 and 5 are present. Node 1 and 5 have 1 connection point each and node 2 has 2 connection points. In total there must be 4 connection points. Hence, the graph in this example has 3 nodes and 2 edges (lines).

Comment: What is a 'connection point'? Is the number of connection points always just twice the number of edges? Also (sorry to be annoying), you mentioned in the title that the graph had to be [connected](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConnectedGraph.html), a term that has a very precise definition, but you didn't mention that in the text. Is this a requirement for the graph?

Comment: I added a figure in the description of the problem. Does it help? I would like both solutions - when the graph must be connected and when this is not a restriction. Thank you for the help!

Comment: You need to be very clear what you mean by "how many graphs". There are three possible ways your graphs could be distinguished from one another: 1) All 16 possible vertices have a unique label. 2) Vertices are only labeled by type, i.e. two type 2 vertices are indistinguishable. 3) Vertices are unlabeled, i.e. isomorphic graphs are indistinguishable. Which are you interested in?

Comment: I am interested in "1) All 16 possible vertices have a unique label.". Also "how many graphs" refers to completing this sentence "Given V=16 possible nodes, each characterized by 1, 2, or 3 connection points (as defined before), one can build maximum X graphs."

Comment: In that case, if I'm understanding you correctly, your problem is equivalent to the following: Determine the number of vertex-labeled graphs with at most 5 vertices of degree 1 (Type 1, 5, and 7), at most 6 vertices of degree 2 (Type 2, 3, and 6), and at most 5 vertices of degree 3 (Type 4 and 8). Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. That's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computing numbers of non-isomorphic graphs with various parameters is not an easy task. Your best bet is to use a program like [nauty](http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/nauty/) to help you generate them. [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) is free and is equipped with a lot of nice graph theory tools, including nauty. Here is a Sage function that will print, sequentially, the number of graphs you are looking for on $0,1,\dots,M$ vertices:

```
def generate(M):
    for n in range(M+1):
        c = 0
        for G in graphs.nauty_geng(str(n) + " -d1 -D3"):
            D = G.degree_sequence()
            if D.count(1) <= 5 and D.count(2) <= 6 and D.count(3) <=5:
                 c = c+((factorial(5)*factorial(6)*factorial(5))/(factorial(5-D.count(1))*factorial(6-D.count(2))*factorial(5-D.count(3))*G.automorphism_group().order()))
        print n, c
```

Let me point out some parts of the code.

```
graphs.nauty_geng(str(n) + " -d1 -D3")
```

This generates all non-isomorphic graphs on $n$ vertices with minimum degree 1 and maximum degree 3.

```
if D.count(1) <= 5 and D.count(2) <= 6 and D.count(3) <=5:
```

This restricts to only graphs with at most 5 vertices of degree 1, at most 6 vertices of degree 2, and at most 5 vertices of degree 3.

```
 c = c+((factorial(5)*factorial(6)*factorial(5))/(5-factorial(D.count(1))*factorial(6-D.count(2))*factorial(5-D.count(3))*G.automorphism_group().order()))
```

The number of ways to assign labels 1,2,3,4,5 to the $n_1$ vertices of degree 1, labels 6,7,8,9,10,11 to the $n_2$ vertices of degree 2, and labels 12,13,14,15,16 to the $n_3$ vertices of degree 3 is: $\left(\frac{5!}{(5-n_1)!}\right)\left(\frac{6!}{(6-n_2)!}\right)\left(\frac{5!}{(5-n_3)!}\right)$. But since we may permute the vertices according to any automorphism of $G$ to obtain an equivalent labeling, we have an overcount of $|\mathrm{Aut}(G)|$, where $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ is the automorphism group of $G$.

Now the output. The code runs fairly slowly past $M=10$. Here are some partial results:

```
0 0
1 0
2 10
3 80
4 940
5 9232
6 90470 
7 827620
8 6736970
9 49085240
10 316700810
11 1679283400
12 6905931400
```

I imagine it will take quite a bit more time to compute 13,14,15, and 16, so I've stopped it for now.

Comment: This helps a lot, but it's not completely clear to me. Could you also provide me a reference where I can find this formula explained in more detail?  Also, is this number usually bigger than 2^(n 2)^T?

Comment: There are n_1=5 vertices of degree one, n_2=6 vertices of degree two and n_3 = 5 vertices of degree three. Do I obtain division by zero? Also, why use permutations instead of combinations?

Comment: The number of vertices of varying degrees changes depending on how large the graph is. If there are only 2 vertices in the graph, it cannot have 5 vertices of degree 1. You don't obtain division by zero because 0! is defined to be 1.

Comment: Let me use the case $n=2$ as an example. If you have only two vertices, they must be connected to one another. So you have two vertices of degree 1. There are 5 labels for the vertices of degree 1: 1,2,3,4,5. You can pick the label for the first vertex in 5 ways, and once it is chosen, you can pick the label for the second vertex in 4 ways. So, 20 total. But choosing, say 1 for the first vertex and 2 for the second is equivalent to choosing 2 for the first and 1 for the second. We overcounted by double (which is |Aut(K_2)|), so there are 10 possibilities.

Comment: This improves even more my understanding, thank you! From your example I see that $|Aut(K_2)|)$ is actually a negative value. I also checked for $n=5$ (with $n_1=3$, $n_2=1$ and $n_3=1$), but now it's positive, because I obtain no. of graphs $= 9232 = 1800+|Aut(K_2)|)$. So |Aut(K_2)|) must be positive and not directly proportional to n. I can imagine that $|Aut(K_2)|)$ is also difficult to calculate when the vertices have different degrees. But I would like to fully understand your formula. Can you can recommend me a book, or article for that?

Comment: I am working with another person on a topic including this, and, at some point, this person mentioned that there are $2^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$ graphs. I don't think that's correct (because we have different degrees for different edges). Hence, I am trying to be sure I understand your reasoning.

Comment: $|\mathrm{Aut}(K_2)|=2$, it is not a negative value. You divide by $|\mathrm{Aut}(G)|$ at the end. In the case of $n=5$, there are many different possible values for $n_1$, $n_2$, and $n_3$. You won't find the total number of graphs for $n=5$ by simply plugging in one set of possible values. You need to analyze all possible graphs. $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ is a group, so any introductory group theory book would be useful basic knowledge, and you may want to read introductory graph theory and combinatorics books as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14608/discussion-between-perry-iverson-and-user2061773).